# Error in table 'sys.sysbinobjs' on master database

Tags: sql-server, dbcc-checkdb, service-pack

We have a SQL server DatabaseIntegrityCheck job to check the SYSTEM_DATABASES, and it shows an error message below in the logs now:

> Msg 2570, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Page (1:354), slot 28 in object ID
>   58, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980511744, alloc unit ID
>   281474980511744 (type "In-row data"). Column "name" value is out of
>   range for data type "nvarchar". Update column to a legal value.
>   CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table
>   'sys.sysbinobjs' (object ID 58). CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and
>   1 consistency errors in database 'master'.

Recommendation is to install SP4 - already done and problem still exists.

Any thoughts please other than rebuild master - no backup available unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

**There's nothing you can do to fix it**, I'm afraid, without a backup, you can't fix errors in system tables like this and I actually would've been surprised if installing SP4 would've worked.

**The best (and probably only) way to resolve this is to create a brand-new, clean install of SQL Server** somewhere else, then restore all of users database there, and script out your logins and jobs etc. to the new site.

Not ideal, I know, and a bit time consuming perhaps, but easy to do and it'll definitely solve your problem. You might be able to sell it as/use it as an opportunity to upgrade everything, spec the system exactly who you'd like it and get everything updated. There will be some downtime (but this can be minimised).

[This](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=118787) is similar to your situation (but perhaps worse) and Paul Randal's reply puts it quite succinctly. [This on SSC](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1082296-1550-1.aspx) is another similar one, but not answers (except a confirmation that there's not a lot you can do). [Finally, this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b81ccacd-82dc-4a0d-850c-dbb44020d998/dbcc-checkdb-master-error-2570-in-syssysbinobjs?forum=sqldatabaseengine) explores the problem as well - same conclusion.

Comment: So is a master database rebuild no good either ?